# Theming login page--user--login.tpl.php

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to theme the login user page and it seems that I'm missing something and I can't figure out what it is.

here is what I did:

I've added this code to my template.php:

```
 function mxblog_theme() {
  $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mxblog') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'page--user--login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'mxblog_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
return $items;
}
```

and this that I'm trying to render in the page--user--login.tpl.php

```
   print drupal_render($form['name']);
    print drupal_render($form['pass']);
```

```
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['actions']);
```

Comment: Can you define "missing something"? And what the objective is?

Comment: I'm basically trying to achieve this : http://dannyenglander.com/blog/customizing-user-login-page-drupal-7 though 'user-login.tpl.php' isn't being recognize but 'page--user--login.tpl.php' is

Comment: That's because you defined the template name above as page--user--login, and not user-login.

Comment: Well I did try to set as user-login and no luck it doesn't display of the drupal-render at all (you can see the screenshot https://postimg.org/image/ldz7miaqj/ )

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track but yes, as defined above, the template would be `user-login.tpl.php`. Did you clear all Drupal caches a few times? Where are you putting that template? Can you put a kpr function in the template to see what it prints out?

Comment: Yes I did clear the caches MANY times :p and I'm putting the template.php in /www/sites/all/themes/mxblog directory and the tpl.php in /www/sites/all/themes/mxblog/tpl directory. Not to sound silly but I don't know what kpr is ? I'm very unsure about how to do what you suggested

Comment: You need to ask a question to clarify what you exactly need.

Comment: I'd like to know why I cannot print any of the name or pass field ? knowing I followed exactly the steps as mentionned in this tutorial : http://dannyenglander.com/blog/customizing-user-login-page-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

When using page--user--login.tpl.php you have to manually fetch the user login form, as your overriding the entire page template not just the form.

You can either include this directly in the template (along with any other markup):

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login'));
```

Or in your mxblog_preprocess_user_login() function must return the form:

```
function mxblog_preprocess_user_login(&$variables){
  $variables['form'] = drupal_get_form('user_login');
}
```

then in the template you should be able to to do as you want:

```
print drupal_render($form['name']);
print drupal_render($form['pass']);
print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
print drupal_render($form['actions']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers :)
For those who are interested, here is what I did:

I created a user-login.tpl.php (note the single '-')
and then I added a background image:

.page-user-login  {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

background: url('xxx/login_BG_rezised.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}

LES PROS DU BTP ONT LA PAROLE 
  Votre média pour s'informer et communiquer.

```
<div class="login-page">
```

```
<form class="login-form">

<span class = "login-form-info"> Inscription rapide et GRATUITE. </span>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Nom utilisateur" name="name" id="edit-name" required="required" class="form-text required"/>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="pass" id="edit-pass" required="required" class="form-text required" />

<input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-user-login" value="user_login"  />
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Connectez-vous" class="form-submit" />

<p class="message">Pas de compte? <a target="_blank" href="https://xxx/user/register">Créez votre compte</a></p>
<p class="message">Mot de passe oublié? <a target="_blank" href="https://xxx/user/password">Renvoyez le moi</a></p>
```

added some css style for the form to look the way I wanted.